# Rails Handling User specific timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I want to display date times created by other users in the time zone the current user is logged in.

I have come across

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)' and
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

But how can I set this to the timezone of user logged in currently, and will it save the date time saved by other users in their timezone and view to other users in their specific timezone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider this code in your `ApplicationController`.

```
around_action :switch_time_zone, :if => :current_user

def switch_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
end
```

It wraps the current request with `Time.use_zone( current_user.time_zone )`, which sets the app's current time zone to be the current user's time zone for the entire request and should cause all of your times to be rendered out in the current user's time zone, unless specifically converted to a time zone.

Comment: Thanks, the article you shared is very helpful

Comment: This is actually really genius. Just implemented it so I'm not sure if it has any side effects or implications.

Comment: It should be `around_action`, not `before_action `
http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised?view=comments#comment_161729

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5.2/

Comment: Agree with previous comment. This method is error prone. Highly recommend to use `around_filter`

Answer (score 6):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :set_time_zone

  def set_time_zone
    if logged_in?
      Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone) { yield }
    else
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5.2/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone-3D

Answer (score 3):

Use this Gem https://github.com/basecamp/local_time

```
<%= local_time(@time.created_at) %>
```

you just have to pass the object like this and it will render the local time of the user logged in. No need to get the local time zone of the current user. It makes time rendering very peaceful :P

Answer (score 1):

We have a asian-europe interacting website. We save everything in UTC time

then we just give the time for the users timezone.

```
=comment.created_at.in_time_zone
```

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to determine user's timezone on the client side and pass it to the controller. You can set it in a coockie:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var tz = jstz.determine();
  $.cookie('timezone', tz.name(), { path: '/' });
});
```

In then in your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :set_user_time_zone

  private

  def set_user_time_zone
    timezone = Time.find_zone(cookies[:timezone])
    Time.use_zone(timezone) { yield }
  end
end
```